# Choose random value from one array Firestore (Firebase)

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a Posts node, which is the user's timeline.

Sample:

```
TIMELINE_INDEX
- ID_POST_1
- ID_POST_2
- ID_POST_3
- ID_POST_4
- ID_POST_5
- ID_POST_6
- ID_POST_7
```

**I have a process that works as follows:**

- From time to time I call a function (Cloud Functions) that inserts a new record in the user's timeline.

**What I need to do:**

I would like to insert a record that is on another node. I have a node called ADS (advertising):

```
ADS
- ID_AD_1
- ID_AD_2
- ID_AD_3
- ID_AD_4
- ID_AD_5
```

I need help to access this ADS node, pick a random ID and pick up its values.
From here I can perform the insertion in the timeline.

Access model to the ADS node - Sample:
**Only here I need to choose a random value.**

```
var adsRef = db.collection('ads');
var allAds = adsRef.get()
    .then(snapshot => {

        //Only here I need to choose a random value.

        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());

        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error getting documents', err);
    });
```

It is intended that the timeline node be this way after insertion of the new die.

```
TIMELINE_INDEX
- ID_POST_1
- ID_AD_4
- ID_POST_2
- ID_POST_3
- ID_POST_4
- ID_POST_5
- ID_POST_6
- ID_POST_7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate a random integer between the range of 0 and the length of your `snapshot` variable.

```
var adsRef = db.collection('ads');
var allAds = adsRef.get()
    .then(snapshot => {

    // Grab a random item from the snapshots
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (snapshots.length - 0 + 1) + snapshots.length);

    // Log the information from this snapshot
    console.log(snapshots[random].id, '=>', snapshots[random].data());

})
.catch(err => {
    console.log('Error getting documents', err);
});
```

Comment: did not work. From the error :(Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at adsRef.get.then.snapshot (/user_code/lib/index.js:64:37). I could not define "length" did not have it, I left it like this (var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (snapshot.size - 0 + 1) + snapshot.size))and the rest is the same as your model. @Roberrrt